# Custom request name in Gatling report in karate?

Tags: karate

While performing the performance test using Karate-Gatling the report contains the complete URL under the statistic request section. Can it be possible to customize that request name?
Like it was in Gatling

```
scenario("MyScenario")
 .exec(http("RequestName").get("url"))
```

Comment: please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#nameresolver

Comment: Hi @peter my question is around http("RequestName") how will I set the custom request name in the report?

Comment: if the link does not answer your question, consider it not supported. I think it does. try it and see. contribute code if needed. thanks